# Creates package but no export

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

My job completes with no error.  The logs show "accuracy", "auc", and other statistical measures of my model. ML-engine creates a package subdirectory, and a tar under that, as expected.  But, there's no export directory, checkpoint, eval, graph or any other artifact that I'm accustom to seeing when I train locally. Am I missing something simple with the command I'm using to call the service?

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
--job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
--runtime-version 1.0 \
--module-name trainer.task \
--package-path trainer/ \
--region $REGION \
-- \
--model_type wide \
--train_data $TRAIN_DATA \
--test_data $TEST_DATA \
--train_steps 1000 \
--verbose-logging true
```

The logs show this: model directory = /tmp/tmpS7Z2bq
But I was expecting my model to go to the GCS bucket I defined in $OUTPUT_PATH.

I'm following the steps under "Run a single-instance trainer in the cloud" from the [getting started docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/getting-started-training-prediction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could show where and how you declare the $OUTPUT_PATH?

Also the model directory, might be the directory within the $OUTPUT_PATH where you could find the model of that specific Job.

Comment: correct.  I wasn't actually specifying the model directory as I thought I was.